# C# Copying files from local machine to remote share failed

Tags: c#, .net

I'm copying `xml` files from local machine to remote share with simple way

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

// composing dt

string file = "test.xml";
string path = Path.Combine(@"C:\local\path", file);
string path2 = Path.Combine(@"\\path\to\remote\share", file);

if (File.Exists(path2)) File.Delete(path2);
dt.WriteXml(path);
File.Copy(path, path2);
```

I've noticed that sometimes copying unexpectedly ends in the middle of the file.
So I have to compare source and target file to be sure that it has been fully copied.

How to force successful copying without such comparing?

Comment: Why are you doing the copy instead of writing the file directly to path2?

Comment: @Esko because of copying problem, in order to keep source file.

Comment: When the file seems corrupt, is the source file also corrupt?

Comment: Path2 is already deleted, this is writing to two places

Comment: @Esko when I was writing file directly, there was the same problem. I guess that problem is unstable connection.

Comment: @Esko no, source file is always unbroken

Comment: @AntoshaShmonoff Then I'm afraid there is not much we can help you with. The code is fine, the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: @Esko should I use something like stream to enforce copying?

Comment: is it possible that the file already exists in the location youre trying to copy to? if so, you need a true \ false boolean in the overload to overwrite the existing file.  What is the error message youre getting

Comment: @SimonPrice The op is checking if the file exists before the copy and even if not the copy would overwrite the file.

Comment: @AntoshaShmonoff I always try to find the real problem instead of trying to hack a solution, diagnose and fix the network problems?

Comment: @Esko unfortunately, network fixing is beyond my ability in this case

Comment: The network is not under your program's control and is *always* subject to the possibility of intermittent faults or loss of availability. You need to write code that can cope with these situations - using whichever strategies you deem fit (e.g. a number retries with increasing sleeps between each one before declaring failure)

Answer (score 2):

General causes in file copy is a timeout, access deny or network outage. 
Put a try-catch around copy operation 1st to identify the reason behind in-between stopping. 
If you can do the same operation to *another* local folder, and then successfully **start** copy to network, the only reason can be network instability. 
Try with a very small size file (some KBs) to see if the operation is successful. This will try to address the timeout issue due to file size.

For very large files, you have to setup a sender and reciever apps. You can use WCF Chunking or Streaming as described in this MSDN post https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webapps/2012/09/06/wcf-chunking/

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest **comparing the check-sum of source and destination file** to know whether the copy was successful or not. If unsuccessful, you may employ different strategies to either retry or fail-fast depending on what is the requirement.

```
class Program
{
    private string fileName = "myFile.xml";
    private string sourcePath = @"d:\source\" + fileName;        
    private string destinationPath = @"d:\destination\" + fileName;


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {           
        (new Program()).Run();
    }

    void Run()
    {
        PrepareSourceFile();
        CopyFile();
    }

    private void PrepareSourceFile()
    {
        DataTable helloWorldData = new DataTable("HelloWorld");            
        helloWorldData.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Greetings"));
        DataRow dr = helloWorldData.NewRow();
        dr["Greetings"] = "Ola!";
        helloWorldData.Rows.Add(dr);
        helloWorldData.WriteXml(sourcePath);
    }

    private void CopyFile()
    {
        int numberOfRetries = 3; // I want to retry at least these many times before giving up.
        do
        {   
            try
            {
                File.Copy(sourcePath, destinationPath, true);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (CompareChecksum())
                    numberOfRetries = 0;
            }


        } while (numberOfRetries > 0);
    }


    private bool CompareChecksum()
    {
        bool doesChecksumMatch = false;
        if (GetChecksum(sourcePath) == GetChecksum(destinationPath))
            doesChecksumMatch = true;
        return doesChecksumMatch;
    }

    private string GetChecksum(string file)
    {
        using (FileStream stream = File.OpenRead(file))
        {
            SHA256Managed sha = new SHA256Managed();
            byte[] checksum = sha.ComputeHash(stream);
            return BitConverter.ToString(checksum).Replace("-", String.Empty);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks but it's too complicated. I just comparing files size for checking